# Using Ant tasks with Flash Builder 4

Tags: ant, flex4, flash-builder

Can someone help me get started with using ant in Flash Builder 4. I have never used ant before so I'm a complete novice. I will need to know how to get it installed in the first place, and how to do the basics.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The fact that the article (linked to by both answers) is no longer available is a prime example of why SO answers should not be links alone.

Here are my experiences as of 02-2011 on Flash Builder 10.1:

- Select "Install New Software..." from the "Help" menu
- Enter "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/" <sup>1</sup>
- After the list refreshes, expand "Programming Languages" <sup>2</sup>
- Check "Eclipse Java Development Tools" <sup>2</sup>
- Click "Next", "I Agree" etc

<sup>1</sup> If you are running a later version of Flash Builder, this URL may be incorrect. If so, click "Available Software Sites" in the install software dialog and enable the closest looking URL (it should be similar to "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo")

<sup>2</sup> If either option is not available, try unchecking "Show only the latest version of available software"

Answer (score 0):

I just read a good article on using Ant but it was for Flex Builder 3, from the [Adobe Developer Connection](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_ant_pt1_print.html).

I couldn't find any good ones detailing Ant use with Flash Builder 4, but here's one [article](http://elromdesign.com/blog/2010/07/08/flashbuilder-4-tip-install-ant-prospective-in-eclipse-version-351/) explaining installation for Flash Builder 4.  You can probably use the build files from the Adobe Developer Connection article to get an understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Since Flash Builder 4 is just Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo) with one of Adobe's plugins, you can use all the lessons learned from Eclipse:

http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-81_basics.htm

http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/anttdg2_ch11/index.html?page=1